# Update user attribute from Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

How can I in Rails write a Coffeescript function to update a database column? I guess an Ajax call of sorts would be ideal:

```
id = $('#document').attr('data-document-id')
$.ajax
  url: "/documents/#{id}/update_attr"
  type: "GET"
  success: (data) ->
    console.log(data)
```

Is something like this the only way? Or is there something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, keep in mind that frontend code (html, css, js) cannot access the database directly. So you need an AJAX request.

REST best practices would require you to use a POST/PUT/PATCH method instead of the GET method which should never change the state of the application.

Also, you are not passing any value to the Rails backend.

```
$.ajax
   url: "/whatever/#{id}"
   type 'POST'
   data:
     key: value
   success: (data)->
     console.log data
```

On the Rails side you need to setup the appropriate route in **config/routes.rb**:

```
post '/whatever/:id', to: 'some_controller#some_action'
```

Still ideally, following the best practices, you probably have some sort of

```
resources :apples
```

already mapped to an ApplesController. You now have to implement the action, which will be like this:

```
def update
  @object = Whatever.find(params[:id])
  if @object.update(key: params[:key]
    render json: { success: 1 }
  else
    render json: { success: 0 }
  end
end
```

That implementation is not complete (it does not handle HTML requests, multi-key updates and other fancy things), but still it should solve your problem.